# Set handler jQuery fileupload on all element in document

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I set handler by:

```
$(".uploads_files_answers").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    progressInterval: 10,
    progressall: function (e, data) {
         $('#progress .file-load-bar').css('width', '100%');
    },
    error: error_file_downloading,
    done: function (e, data) {  
        console.log('Select file')
    }
});
```

and then remove and add element from page by

```
let file_input_elements = $(".uploads_files_answers")
file_input_elements.remove()
file_input_elements.appendTo(main_form)
```

handler was removed too.

How I can set fileupload handlers on all  **file_input_elements** in document, that I need removing and adding dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move the elements without destroying their event handlers, you can just call `appendTo()` without `remove()`:

```
let file_input_elements = $(".uploads_files_answers")
file_input_elements.appendTo(main_form);
```

If, for whatever reason you wanted to remove the elements from the DOM and then re-attach them at a later point still with the event handlers intact, use `detach()` instead of `remove()`:

```
let file_input_elements = $(".uploads_files_answers").detach();

// at some other point later in the page lifecycle...
file_input_elements.appendTo(main_form);
```

Comment: this solution approaches for me. But do you now how to add handler on all elements, that not present in document on load and created during page live?